# Count() of active users from permission set

Tags: soql, query, permission-sets

I have below query which fetching the Active users from the permission set. But I need a `count()` of active users.
Below is the query I am using :

```
SELECT Id, 
       AssigneeId,
       PermissionSet.Name 
 FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
 WHERE Assignee.isActive = false and permissionSet.Name='Test_Permission'
```

Comment: You need to count the records number of this query ?

Comment: Yes.I need a count of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Assignee.isActive = true and permissionSet.Name='Test_Permission'
```

If you want only the count, you can just use `count(id)` to get the count. But if you want other values you can go with the previous answer.

Thanks. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code :

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> assignmentList = [SELECT Id, 
       AssigneeId,
       PermissionSet.Name 
 FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
 WHERE Assignee.isActive = false and permissionSet.Name='Test_Permission'];

Integer recordsNumber = assignmentList.size();
```